# Using C# code to simulate textbox filling and button pressing

Tags: c#, windows

I'm working on a C# program which automates tasks. For example, my program opens an external application (specifically mstsc.exe) and uses the application. I want to write code which fills textboxes with certain values and presses certain buttons. What is the right and most elegant way to implement such operations in a C# 4 code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution for this problem, it´s solved with "SendKeys":

```
var Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\mstsc.exe";

//Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v:" + "PCwg01"; normaly
Proc.Start();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
SendKeys.Send("PCwg01"); //name or IP adress
SendKeys.Send("\r");
```

i hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 2):

if your special target is `mstsc.exe` use [its parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907%28v=ws.10%29):

```
mstsc.exe [<Connection File>] [/v:<Server>[:<Port>]] [/admin] [/f] [/w:<Width> /h:<Height>] [/public] [/span]

mstsc.exe /edit <Connection File>

mstsc.exe /migrate
```

else [**Windows Input Simulator** (C# SendInput Wrapper - Simulate Keyboard and Mouse)](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) is a reliable and open-source library on *CodePlex* for your issue.